# How do I write ≢ in LaTeX?

Tags: relation-symbols

How do I write the symbol ≢ ("not equivalent to") in LaTeX? Is there a way to put a slash through `\equiv`? `\notequiv` doesn't exist.

Comment: you can write `\not\equiv` (which is returned immediately be detexify).

Comment: `\nequiv` with `txfonts` or `pxfonts`